# Safety concerns for traveling the Leh district

Tags: india, leh-india, north-india

I would like to spend some time - around a month exploring [the Leh district in North India](http://wikitravel.org/en/Leh_%28district%29).

Some friends advised me not to go, but they were there a long time ago (10 years or so). I have also seen more recent accounts on the Internet that it might not be a good idea to go there.

I am 34 well travelled man and plan to do some trekking around there if possible.
In the first half I will be with a girl friend and the second alone.
If camping is an option I would not mind it.
Season is August - September.

Is it safe(r) to go now? Anyone been there recently?

Answer (score 3):

Do not take the Srinagar route if you are going now because of the recent protest and most areas of Kashmir are under curfew these days. Manali - Leh route is absolutely fine as far as security is concerned and whole of Ladakh is good as far as security is concerned. Road (travel) Safety is a different aspect and out of the scope of this thread.

Answer (score 2):

It is safe.  Hope you enjoy your travel :)  I traveled to Leh in 2010.  The place should not be missed.

Anu Motors in Manali have a good network of good people.  They extensively travel to Leh and back as part of groups.  You can approach them for more information and help.

Comment: thanks so much Rahul! just one thing... what do you mean exactly by "the place should NOT be missed". what happened?

Comment: "the place should NOT be missed" = Very very beautiful place :)  Colour of sky not seen before.  Clean clean air - no dust! The mountains red, brown and grey against the crisp sky blue :)

Comment: oh ok i understood not missed as "I miss you" kinda way... thanks again!!!!